# Extract data from mysql table

Tags: php

i've this code that works

```
$macrocat = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE cat_parent_id = 0";      
 $result = dbQuery($macrocat);
  while($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
             extract($row); 

   echo ."<h1>".$cat_name."</h1>";
```

}

Now, I'd like to apply a different css style only to the first record extract.

for example:

```
 if (1st record) {

div-class="white" echo $cat_name

} else { div-class="black" echo $cat_name }
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You can add a simple flag.

```
$isFirst = true;
while($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) 
{
    if ($isFirst)
    {
        echo yourfirstdiv;
        $isFirst = false;
    }
    else
    {
        echo yourotherdiv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for CSS definitions...

```
<style>
.div-class{
  /* put your 'black' class definitions here */
}
.div-class:first{
  /* put your 'white' class definitions here */
}
</style>
```